# setcookie в php. не получается из формы взять значение кук

Tags: php

здравствуйте, вроде бы все делаю так, но получается не так...
устанавливаю куки в index.php

```
<?php
setcookie('login', $login);
function clearText($test){
    return htmlspecialchars(trim($test));
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $login = clearText($_POST['login']);
    if (!empty($login)){
        $_COOKIE['login'] = $login;
        header("Location: testcookie.php");
    }
}
?>

  <FORM action = '<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' method = 'POST'>
   <INPUT type = 'text' name = 'login' value = '<?=$_COOKIE['login'];?>'>
   <INPUT type = 'submit' value = 'ok'>
  </FORM>
```

и проверяю их на testcookie.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['login'])){
    echo $_COOKIE['login'];
}else{
    echo 'кука не установлена!';
}
?>
```

но ничего не происходит( переменная $login не передается. если в значении setcookie дать значение например ПРИВЕТ, то кука будет установлена, а так нет... в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: что-то код не отформатировался с кодом в testcookie

Comment: отформатировался)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!empty($login)){
    setcookie('login', $login);
    header("Location: testcookie.php");
}
```

Comment: Я ступил, абсолютно верно! `setcookie('login', $login);` стоит не на своем месте!

Comment: Не на своем месте и не так =)

Comment: Спасибо, действительно все работает! подскажите, почему у меня не получилось? разве местоположение setcookie имеет значение?

Comment: Конечно имеет. Во-первых, вы пытаетесь установить печеньку и задать ей значение переменной login, которой не существует. У вас login принимает значение только в результате обработки формы. А во-вторых, при обработке формы вы пытаетесь записать печеньку, но неправильно, т.е. просто присваиваете ей значение как обычной переменной, а не через setcookie()

Comment: спасибо за пояснение, теперь думаю больше не возникнет таких вопросов) до этого пробовал изучать session_start(); на уровне новичка, как и сейчас в случае с печенья, вот думал, что тут так же можно) теперь думаю разберусь)

Comment: то есть если я Вас сейчас понял, то при моем коде если бы была включена ф-ция Error_Reporting (E_ALL), то у меня бы вышла ошибка E_NOTICE?)

Comment: Да, конечно!

Comment: все тогда понятно ) у меня в php.ini стоит Error_Reporting (E_ALL ~E_NOTICE), короче отключал эту ошибку, иногда она выскакивает когда код вроде бы и работает, но значение пока нет)) сейчас включил и если надо будет, то в коде буду отключать))) еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Вообще в php.ini отобржение ошибок лучше отключить. А для себя на время разработки приложения можно (или даже нужно) в шапке сайта прописать следующие строки:


    ini_set("display_errors","1");
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

Comment: @NoProblems, не должно быть в коде нотисов.